# Floating pane not obeying absolute position relative to parent

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want this floating pane to be initially positioned 40px from the top of the parents position. The current result (shown in the JSFiddle) is `top:140px` instead of the intended `top:40px`.

```
<body class="tundra">
    <div style="height:100px;background-color:blue;"></div>
    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div style="background-color:red;" class="paneClass"></div>
        <div id="simplepane1"></div>
    </div>
</body>

require(["dojox/layout/FloatingPane", "dojo/domReady!"], function(FloatingPane) {
    var floatingPane1 = new FloatingPane({
        class: "paneClass"
    }, document.getElementById("simplepane1"));
    floatingPane1.startup();
});

.paneClass{
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:40px;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9qqtbe4y/4/

You can see how the red `div` positions correctly relative to the parent but the floatingPane does not.

Comment: Looks like FloatingPane is recomputing the position and adding 100px to it... maybe looking at the source code could shed some light?

Comment: I'm looking into that now. Another point of interest is that minimizing then maximizing the floating pane seems to add 100px every time it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Parents position of the floating pane is 100px down from top (this 100px is the height of first div inside class "tundra"). So when it gets instruction of adding 40px more, it moves total 140px from top.

rewriting the HTML code as below, will solve the issue. the change is to set 1st div's position to `relative`

```
<div style="height:100px;background-color:blue;position:relative;"></div>
<div style="background-color:red;" class="paneClass"></div>
<div id="simplepane1"></div>
```

---

```
require(["dojox/layout/FloatingPane", "dojo/domReady!"],
function(FloatingPane) {
var floatingPane1 = new FloatingPane({
    class: "paneClass"
}, document.getElementById("simplepane1"));
floatingPane1.startup();
});
```

---

```
.paneClass{
position:absolute;
top:140px;
left:40px;
width:200px;
height:300px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem at all. Now not even the red `div` is positioned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the floating pane is built as an absolutely positioned element and it's styles are also meant to match that. So when setting 40px from the top of the relative box, it actually adds 100 based on it's parent. Depending on what you're trying to do with this, I would recommend not putting the floating pane inside a div that has an inherent `top` value. If you don't want the floating pane to ever overlap with the top bar, you can look into constraining it inside a box. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/3vtxw/) (not mine) is an example that does just that.

If you don't want care about that, then simply removing the `position: relative` from the containing div and changing the default style of the floating div to be `top: 140px;` will also work.